# Docusign Integrator Key with multiple users

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to make API call from Salesforce to DocuSign that creates an envelope in DocuSign. I don't find any issues there. My query is how to get the integrator key and DocuSign credentials for multiple users and store it in Salesforce to be picked up dynamically for the corresponding user. For Dev, I can use my credentials and Integrator Key to create an envelope. When it comes to multiple users, how should I proceed? Please, can anyone explain to me how this can be achieved?

Comment: Are your multiple users in same DocuSign account as your's or each have their own DocuSign account?

Comment: Hi Amit, they are in the same account

Comment: If all users are in same account as your's then you can use SOBO to call APIs, SOBO is explained in the below link: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to? Integrator keys can be used across accounts and users without issue.

What are you trying to accomplish by using unique integrator keys per user?

Comment: Hi Drew, I'm not sure about using Integrator keys per user. My question was, can we use single integrator key to make Api calls across multiple users.

Comment: Yes. Integrator keys are not tied to accounts or users. A single integrator key will work for any user or account in Demo, and once it's live it will be valid for anyone in the production environment.